# MYSQL Security questions regarding ROOT user

Tags: mysql

The datasource used by my web application connects using the ROOT user. The ROOT user has all privileges assigned.

My concerns are:

1) Should I be using this user (and is it ok / secure) or should I create another user with a more restricted set of rights

2) If I do use another user, how do I cater for all my procs that begin with:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `Blah`()
```

3) Is it a bad idea removing privileges from the ROOT user. For example, if I remove the "DROP" privilege, will I still be able to DROP objects when logging in via the Admin or Query Browser. MY guess would be no and that I shouldn't mess with the privileges.

Any documentation / links / info regarding this would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should absolutely use a restricted user to access the database as much as possible.
2. There are privileges that allow your users to access procedures. I'm not that familiar with it but here's the official documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html
3. Don't mess with root's privileges :)

Comment: So the ROOT user should have ALL privileges but it should not be used for anything, only by the system?

Comment: Or the system administrator. It's often called the "super user", because it's granted to do *anything*. It should only be used during setup or installation. During so-called "production" usage, the root user shouldn't be touched. And I even believe that regular maintainance should leave the root user alone.

Answer (score 0):

No, your application should *not* connect using the root user. You should create and configure a user that has the permissions required by the application and no more.

Answer (score 0):

I usually go with at least three users:

- Root can do everything; changing root's permissions is a recipe for disaster (unless you know exactly what you are doing)
- The application has its own user, and this user has very restrictive permissions - usually just SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE on the tables it needs. In any case, no permissions that would allow schema modifications (CREATE / ALTER TABLE and such).
- A special user which can access the application's database, but nothing else. This user is used for maintenance tasks such as schema upgrades, but not for the application itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to use the root user for any task. You can see it like the system-user: only the system should use it, when it needs it, to do *everything*.

Create a new user and give it only access and priviledges to do what it *should* do. This is called the [principle of least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).

In this case, procedures are part of what a certain user, module or part of a program should do in normal circumstances. Hence, the user you create [owns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) (`DEFINER`) that procedure. You should remove the procedure from the root user and add it to your newly created user. If it's impossible to remove from the root user: then so be it! However:

If a user want to access the procedure, [give](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html) (`GRANT`) them access to it. In the case the root user still owns the procedure, any other user still can be granted to *use* the procedure.

The root user is, as I already mentioned, the system user. If you drop priviledges then any program or user using the root can't do what is expected (being the system-user capable of doing everything), and this cripples your system.

Think about this: how would you add a new database, if you dropped the "ADD DATABASE" privilege from the root user?